# Affine varieties and their ideals (part2)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient), they talk about varieties $V,W$ and the $I(V)$ and $I(W)$ as well as the quotient ideal,

$$I(V):I(W) = I(V - W)$$

Can someone show me a quick proof of the identity?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Have you tried either inclusion?

Comment: @MooS, I m having trouble writing out the definition of the LHS. I know the RHS is $(f \in R : f(x) = 0, x \in V - W )$. I think the LHS is $(f : f I(V) \subset I(W) )$

Comment: You swapped $V$ and $W$...$I:J := \{f : fJ \subset I\}$.

Comment: Right, but I am still wrong no...? Because that's what your (1) suggests...

Comment: Why? If you swap $V$ and $W$, your definition is perfectly right and my answer precisely adresses this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Show

$$I(V):I(W) \supset I(V-W)$$

This is the easy part. By the definition of the ideal quotient, we have to show $I(V-W)I(W) \subset I(V)$ and this immediate: If $f$ vanishes on $V-W$ and $g$ vanishes on $W$, then $fg$ vanishes on all of $V$.

2. Show

$$I(V):I(W) \subset I(V-W)$$

For this we need a crucial ingredient:

**Lemma.** If $W \subset \mathbb A^n$ is an affine variety and $x \notin W$, there is some $f \in I(W)$, such that $f(x) \neq 0$.

*Proof:* Assume the opposite. We then have $I(W) \subset I(\{x\})$. Apply $V$ and get $V(I(W)) \supset V(I(\{x\}))$. For varieties $X$, we have $V(I(X))=X$. Since both are varieties, we have $W \supset \{x\}$, contradiction!

Now let us finish the proof:

Let $f \in I(V):I(W)$ and $x \in V-W$. We have to show $f(x)=0$.

By the lemma above, we have some $g \in I(W)$ with $g(x) \neq 0$. We have $fg \in fI(W) \subset I(V)$, hence $0=f(x)g(x)$. Then $g(x) \neq 0$ implies $f(x)=0$ and we are done.

Comment: Relating to my intial question, for (1), you say we have to show $I(V - W)I(W) \subset I(V)$. I thought in my definition, $f$ is taken to be a an element of the affine space, not $I(V - W)$?

Comment: What you learn in you first course ever: If we have to show $A \subset B$, we take an element of $A$, don't we? You should take some time and think about this proof. The easiest steps seem to be out of reach for you, so you really have to give yourself some time.

Comment: No that's not what I mean. I mean why $I(V - W)I(W)$, but thank you anyways.

Comment: We have to take an arbitrary $f \in I(V-W)$ and show $fI(W) \subset I(V)$. This is the same as showing $I(V-W)I(W) \subset I(V)$.

Comment: okay *now* I get it. Sorry I am slow, thanks for your patience with me.