# Variety of an ideal.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

I am trying to understand the inclusion $Z(I) \setminus Z(J) \subset Z(I:J)$ through the standard definition of a variety (not the closure). I will be borrowing results from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1651792/121097).

$$Z(I) = \{ x : f(x) = 0, \forall f \in I \}.$$

Basically, if $x \in Z(I) \setminus Z(J)$, then $f(x) = 0$ $\forall f \in I$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ for some $ g \in J$. Need to show that $x \in Z(I:J) = \{ x : q(x) = 0, \forall q \in I:J \}$.

If $q \in I:J$, then $qg \in qJ \subset I$, so there is an $f$, such that $qg = f$. As $x \in Z(I)$, $f(x) = g(x)q(x)$ for some $g$. Okay I think I still missing some conclusion sentence to link everything.

Comment: Seriously, you are totally forgetting about quantifiers $\exists$ and $\forall$. You can not do any math without them.

Comment: $g(x) \ne 0$ for all $g \in J$ is false. $x \not \in Z(J)$ only means that there exists an $g \in J$ with $g(x) \ne 0$. Sort out your quantifier hodgepodge by starting from the beginning and writing down what you actually know and what you need to show. Then it won't be hard.

Comment: You are almost done. (The way the choice of $f$ is written down is a bit cumbersome; but this does not matter much for the argument.) Recall that you need to show $q(x)=0$, and what you know about $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: @moonlight, what do you mean? I mean I have $f(x) = 0$, so $g(x)q(x) = 0$. Uh oh, I see a problem, need to justify dividing out $g(x)$...?

Comment: Exactly. And this is the point where you use $g(x) \ne 0$.

Comment: But that's only for *some* $g$? Isn't there a $g$ such that $g(x) = 0$? Isn't that a problem?

Comment: @moonlight, right...?

Comment: Not is not a problem. You want to show $q(x)=0$. It is certainly enough to find **some** $g$ with $g(x) \neq 0$ and $q(x)g(x)=0$.

This like showing $\mathbb R \ni a=0$. If you find one $\mathbb R \ni b \neq 0$ with $ab=0$, you are done, aren't you?

Comment: @Moos Okay I feel dumb for asking now...thanks, to the both of you. I am slow sorry

Comment: The point is, you first fix $x \in Z(I)-Z(J)$. Then you choose $g \in J$ with $g(x) \ne 0$. Then let $q \in (I:J)$ be arbitrary, and the argument continues as above. So, as you can see, there is no problem because you only need to be able to choose one such fixed $g$. That you are confused about this, indicates to me that you are again confused about the quantifiers and the logical setup of the proof. If you try to write everything down in a nice systematic way, this confusion should go away.

Comment: @moonlight, yeah I am idiot... thanks.